# PHP Validation algorithm

Tags: php, validation

I'm building an website in PHP which I need to validate user input as 'New Password' and 'Confirm Password' but it isn't working.

full page available on this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9sO6GgTNt3JczVIT3dWdlJYYUk/view?usp=sharing)

```
$rstPwd1 = $_POST['rstPwd1'];
$rstPwd2 = $_POST['rstPwd2'];

if(empty($rstPwd1) && empty($rstPwd2)){
    echo "Please fill in both fields!";
}
else{
    if(empty($rstPwd1) || empty($rstPwd2)){
        if(empty($rstPwd1)){
            echo "Please fill in 'New Password' field!";
        }
        if(empty($rstPwd2)){
            echo "Please fill in 'Confirm Password' field!";
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($rstPwd1 != $rstPwd2){
            echo "Passwords aren't matching!";
        }
        else {
            if(strlen($rstPwd1) <= 7) {
                echo "Password must be minimum 8 characters long!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say it isn't working, what exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: @Terry I mean it doesn't validate it. If we talk about flow it never gets even in first block. When I put both fields empty still it's passes validation

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that script. I tried it and changed the passwords from $rstPwd1 = $_POST['rstPwd1']; to $rstPwd1 = ""; and the same for $rstPwd1, it fails validation. It is most likey something to do with how you are submitting the data

Comment: Have tested it with a form and POST'ing the data and it works also. Can you post your form?

Comment: I've uploaded it on google drive please check [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9sO6GgTNt3JczVIT3dWdlJYYUk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: In your form in the link posted above, you have different input field names. 'resetpasword1' is not the same as 'rstPwd1'.

Comment: @Progrock I know I just made some changes while putting question here. I kept formatting same

Comment: Where is $c_script defined? I get `<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: c_script in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\stackoverflow\3\index.php</b> on line <b>100</b><br />
?stage=2` if I inspect the form

Comment: It is defined in init.inc.php, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

Comment: Your linked code, has many responsibilities, which makes it difficult to follow.  It is also possible currently to change any users password by jumping and posting straight to stage 4 (if the code was working).

Comment: I know security is not that important now as this is just a college mini project and code is working fine

Comment: Correct there was nothing wrong with the script but the way I treating those variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I place your validation rules in a function, it's possible to test different inputs, and see if they work as expected.

```
<?php
function reset_password_validator($password, $repeat_password) {
    if(empty($password) && empty($repeat_password)){
        echo "Please fill in both fields!";
    }
    else{
        if(empty($password) || empty($repeat_password)){
            if(empty($password)){
                echo "Please fill in 'New Password' field!";
            }
            if(empty($repeat_password)){
                echo "Please fill in 'Confirm Password' field!";
            }
        }
        else {
            if ($password != $repeat_password){
                echo "Passwords aren't matching!";
            }
            else {
                if(strlen($password) <= 7) {
                    echo "Password must be minimum 8 characters long!";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Run through some values:

```
$inputs = array(
    array('',''),
    array('foo', ''),
    array('foo', 'bar'),
    array('', 'bar'),
    array('foo', 'foo'),
    array('password', 'password')
);

foreach($inputs as $pair)
{
    printf("Validating: '%s' and '%s'\n", $pair[0], $pair[1]);
    reset_password_validator($pair[0], $pair[1]);
    print "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Validating: '' and ''
Please fill in both fields!
Validating: 'foo' and ''
Please fill in 'Confirm Password' field!
Validating: 'foo' and 'bar'
Passwords aren't matching!
Validating: '' and 'bar'
Please fill in 'New Password' field!
Validating: 'foo' and 'foo'
Password must be minimum 8 characters long!
Validating: 'password' and 'password'
```

I'd be tempted to simplify with a generic error, and remove the length requirement:

```
if(empty($password) || $password !== $repeat_password) {
    $error = 'Password fields must match and not be empty.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check when someone clicks the submit button.

If there are a few forms on the site like

```
<form action="" method="get">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="submit_get1">
</form>
<form action="" method="get">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="submit_get2">
</form>
<form action="" method="post">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="submit_post1">
</form>
<form action="" method="post">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="submit_post2">
</form>
```

you can access them with PHP as follows:

```
if (isset($_GET["submit_get1"])) {
    echo "submit_get1";
}

if (isset($_GET["submit_get2"])) {
    echo "submit_get2";
}

if (isset($_POST["submit_post1"])) {
    echo "submit_post1";
}
if (isset($_POST["submit_post2"])) {
    echo "submit_post2";
}
```

Comment: What if I'm using both methods in the page?

Comment: Please check the updated link above in which my full php page is available